# DispatcherTimer doesn't seem to be firing

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a wpf app that opens and closes relays for a specified amount of time and counts down the time remaining in a label.  When I click my button, the relays fire as I expect but the tick event doesn't seem to fire as the loop (script) keeps executing.  If I comment out all but the dispatcher timer code, the timer works fine, counting down to 0 as expected.  Am I missing something?  Thanks.

```
private void btnRun_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();

        Script script = new Script(random, relays);
        script.Name = comboBoxSelectedScript.SelectedItem.ToString();

        // Stuck in this loop
        while (time > TimeSpan.Zero)
            script.Run();
    }       

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (time >= TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            lblScriptTimeRemaining.Content = time.ToString("c");
            time = time.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-1));
        }
        else
            timer.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: Don't put a while in a button click handler this will block the UI thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DispatcherTimer` runs on the UI thread, and your while loop blocks the UI thread. So the `timer_Tick` method won't run (which is required to change the value of `time`, and break out of the loop).